# Failing to execute the jar file using java -jar command

Tags: java, jar

I have created a jar file usign maven2 build. I am trying to run that jar file using the command:

```
java -jar sample.jar com.app.Test
```

`Test` being the class which is having the main method. But i am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Can any one help me to solve this exception and run the jar file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you include a MANIFEST file in your jar that specifies the main class to run? See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest

Comment: Maybe the manifest file is broken? Can you open the jar file and check that the main class is properly defined in META-INF/Manifest ?

Comment: can you run it outside of the jar and it works?

Comment: Did you create a manifest file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to run the Test class, you should use

```
 java -cp sample.jar com.app.Test
```

This way, you add the jar to the classpath and then run the specified main class.

What `java -jar` does is that it executes a runnable jar file (which defines its own main class in the manifest file). Any parameters after that would not be used to specify the class, but end up in the String array passed to the main method.

So if you have a properly constructed runnable jar file, it should just be

```
java -jar sample.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Thilo, how to specify entry class in manifest file at the time of building the jar?

Comment: `Main-Class: com.app.Test`  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest

Comment: Or, using Maven (which can also bundle in all dependencies, which is something you want): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022032/building-a-runnable-jar-with-maven-2

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Maven, you may need to use maven's install command.  You can find the format here
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do need a manifest and a Main-Class attribute, if you don't have one.
If you are using java 7 a bug is filed here https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7067922