# Jar file won't run via command prompt or double-click

Tags: java, command-line, jar, executable-jar

I recently finished a project which works as it is supposed to in my Eclipse IDE as both multiple files and as a single file.

Eclipse exports the jar file and only makes noise about the warnings.

When I go to run the jar file with a double-click, the cursor seems to flash to a hourglass for less than a second and then nothing. When I try to run the jar file from the command line with `java -jar myJarFile.jar` the command prompt window seems to wait a second and then brings the file path line and cursor with no errors and no other messages.

I have double checked both my Path variable and that I have the latest version of Java installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add logging statements to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread: [Failing to execute the jar file using java -jar command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192647/failing-to-execute-the-jar-file-using-java-jar-command)

Basically, what you need to do is when you run the jar, you need to specify the class to be executed in the command line, like so:

```
java -cp test.jar com.app.ClassName
```

Comment: Just tried that and got the response listed above in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just make a jar file, or a runnable jar file? If you only did the former then it will not execute on a double click. So it's Right Click the project in Eclipse -> Export -> Runnable JAR File -> Choose the appropriate Launch Configuration -> Choose where you want it to go.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that your application code is in the jar file:

```
jar tf myJarFile.jar
```

Confirm that your application's main class is listed in the `Main-Class` attribute in the manifest, and that any other jar files needed by your application are listed in the `Class-Path` attribute:

```
jar xf myJarFile.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Try running with verbose logging of classes being loaded; this should show if some necessary class can't be found:

```
java -verbose:class -jar myJarFile.jar
```