# No persistence provider WHEN exporting jar file

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, export

I have a maven desktop project that uses JPA as persistent layer; this layer deals with one MySQL database and one SQL Server database.

When I run it inside Eclipse, there is no problema; but when I try to export it outside the output when I run jar the console prints the famous:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence provider for
 EntityManager named axaptaUnitName
```

`axaptaUnitName` is the unit that deals with SQL Server. I have tried all three type of exportation from Eclipse, extract required libraries into JAR, package into JAR, and copy in external folder; none of them works.

All libraries (including the connector with SQL Server) are correctly added to classpath; inside Eclipse all works perfect; so I assume that it's some kind of exportation problem.
Any suggestions?

Edit: I've tried to replace Microsoft SQL driver with JTDS driver; but the issue still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one solution:

Instead of exporting project with Eclipse, I have generated a jar with Maven [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022032/building-a-runnable-jar-with-maven-2).

Answer (score 1):

Here is Work around for this.

1. I simply exported it as a runnable Jar with option - "Extract required libraries into generated Jar".
2. Opened generated Jar with a archiever software.
3. Then I found there is no "Persistence.xml" in META-INF folder.
4. I dragged my "Persistence.xml" file in that META-INF folder in achiever's window itself.
5. Closed archiever program.

After that, the PersistenceException was disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use the "uber-jar" method where all dependency jars are exploded into one big jar. The problem with this approach is if the jar has files with same relative path they could override each other. Consider this scneario:

```
// contents of A.jar
com/foo/Class1.class
com/foo/Class2.class
META-INF/persistence.xml

// contents of B.jar
com/bar/Class1.class
com/bar/Class2.class
META-INF/persistence.xml
```

When A.jar and B.jar are exploded and re-packaged into Uber.jar, the earlier META-INF/persistence.xml will get overwritten causing errors / unwanted behavior

A better solution to deploy your standalone application is to keep all dependencies in their original jar packaging, place them in a single folder and run using command like this (windows):

```
java -cp "dependency/;myprog.jar" com.foo.MyMainClass
```

(all dependency jars are placed on the folder "dependency")