# Build an executable jar using maven in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

First of all, I am new in maven...

I am trying to build a jar executable of my app using maven but without success.

My pom.xml configuration file is as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>distributed.analyzer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>analyzer</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.distributed.analyzer.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>            
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

From eclipse, I perfom a run as -> maven build...

and then in Goals field I specify deploy (Is it correct if I want to obtain an executable jar in my machine?)

Finally I click on 'Run' button and it starts to build the jar but below error appears:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building analyzer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\target\distributed.analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] Installing D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\target\distributed.analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\A\.m2\repository\com\distributed.analyzer\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\distributed.analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing D:\eclipse-workspace\DistributedAnalyzer\pom.xml to C:\Users\A\.m2\repository\com\distributed.analyzer\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\distributed.analyzer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ distributed.analyzer ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.595 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-13T00:53:10+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/135M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project distributed.analyzer: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

***UPDATE:***
Executing maven with -X switch:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.442 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-13T01:25:29+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project distributed.analyzer: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project distributed.analyzer: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.getDeploymentRepository(DeployMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: I think someone's already answered this here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022032/building-a-runnable-jar-with-maven-2)

Comment: Well? Did you `Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`?

Comment: @chrylis how can I do this from eclipse? Could you tell me, please?

Comment: @chrylis ok by adding -X option before goals in the goals entry 
field.

Comment: It seems like I need to specify a repository element  in the POM inside distributionManagement but If I only want to make a jar executable of my app in my machine and execute it, is it necessary?

Comment: I was using an incorrect goal. I want to deploy my app into a runnable jar in local, not in a remote repository, so as I was not specifing the remote repository it was failing as normal. Instead of using deploy, in my case the correct goals are: compile package. Doing so works.

Comment: You should simply use `mvn package` which contains `compile` You should take a deeper look into the [life cycle documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). `mvn compile package` will run all life cycle steps incl compile...