# Why do I get "A Java Exception has occurred" after I export my application to Jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jar, export

Well, I exported my application into JAR with eclipse, but now whenever I try running it I get the: "A Java Exception has occurred". When I try to run it through command line it says:

```
C:\Users\Arturas>java -jar D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\Exports\Dantracio_skaiciu
oklis3.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widge
ts/Composite
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more

C:\Users\Arturas>
```

Any solutions to this? I just hate java for this... It never works on desktops when you want it to... sorry I'm really stressed out from this, I'm overreacting...

Any ideas what could cause this? I doesn't work on other computers as well. Right now it's using Java 1.7. And the application runs perfectly on Eclipse.

Comment: When you create a JAR, it only contains classes you've written, not any third-party dependencies. (Like SWT.) When running a project outside the IDE, you need to make a launcher that includes these depedencies on the classpath using the `-cp` parameter to `java.exe`.

Comment: FWIW, Eclipse *should* be capable of producing some sort of distribution package with all the `.jar`s your application needs in one directory.

Comment: @millimoose Uhm, I think that's what I need, I need it to pack everything into one Jar (that's why I chose exporting to jar?). So how can that be done?

Comment: Exporting to JAR pretty much always means "export **my** code into a JAR". (The idea being that you're responsible to setting up the required *classpath* for your app.) Third-party JARs have to be repackaged, or manually included on the classpath. digitaljoel's answer points to a few tools that will do this sort of repackaging.

Comment: (The classpath - or, more generally, the classes available to a classloader -  is an annoyingly nonobvious-yet-essential concept in deploying any sort of Java application. I'd recomment reading up on it, or searching SO for questions asking to explain it. Doing so is a little out of scope for tangential comments.)

Comment: @millimoose Yeah, I cheked out those tools but it feels like I would need a week to get something working with them. :S I just wanted to make a quick desktop application which I coded in like 1.5 hour and now I'm already searching for 5 hours for a way to let it work on a normal computer... Are there any solutions without exporting to jar then? Something easier?

Comment: Sure. Just don't use **any** libraries outside the JDK. (Meaning: there is no easy way to deploy third party libraries on Java. Or on most platforms really, there's some conceptual overhead involved in most that I can recall off the top of my head.)

Comment: Export your project as a runnable jar for a quick solution. That should include the dependent jars. Long term - You need to determine what is causing org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite to be included in your program and delete it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get your dependencies.  Looks like you are depending on swt, which is not part of the core java language.  You'll need to get all the third party jars that you depend on and include them in your classpath.  It runs perfectly on eclipse because eclipse takes care of setting up the classpath for you.

You can set the classpath in your manifest file as described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html), or you could include a script to start your application that will use the `-cp` command when running the jar, or you can use something that will package everything into one monster jar like the solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059851/is-it-possible-to-package-all-the-jar-dependencies-in-one-big-jar).

Comment: The monster jar answer also omits some more current solutions like [Jar Jar Links](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) or the Maven [`shade` plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)