# Issue with main when running jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to run a jar file, and I have created the manifest file and such within eclipse and specified the main entry point. I have tested all my class files and the one I need to work(TestRead.java) keeps giving me this error am not sure why or how to resolve it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaElement
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaElement
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

And below is the command line:

```
java -jar JavaWdslApp.jar
```

Edit: I saved it as a runnable Jar file for the mean time and tried running it but another issue appears telling me the array is out of bounds: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

This is how I call it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String path1 = args[0];
String fileName = args[1];
TagDef tagDef;

String[] operations;
try {
    operations = listOperationsUnique("abc");
    System.out.println("operation:" + operations.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("operation:" + operations[i]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    tagDef = refheader(path1, fileName); 

    System.out.println("=================================================================");
    System.out.println("abc");
    System.out.println(abc);
    System.out.println("=================================================================");

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaElement is packaged in a seperate jar ( i guess XmlSchema jar or something .Check it . I am not 100% ) I suspect when you create ``your`` jar you did not include it in your packaged jar . Hence when you try running it now it is not found  .

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078505/why-do-i-get-a-java-exception-has-occurred-after-i-export-my-application-to-ja)

Comment: Ok I have had a look at the options and saved it as a runnable Jar file for the mean time but am my Array in Main Args is apparently out ofboundsexception, The code runs fine in eclipse, I Have been looking through Stack overflow for a solution but it is strange it cant find the values : String path1 = args[0];
         String fileName = args[1];

Comment: @Studento919 your argument excection is caused by trying to refer to arg[1] . It is undefined . Follow Tomas' answer . Report back if u got any problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error is caused because you are trying to access to args[0] and args[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), while you haven't informed any argument at your command line. It should look similar to this:

```
java -jar JavaWdslApp.jar valueForPath1 valueForFileName
```

I recommend you to check the [java command reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Comment: Just a quick question also is it possible to specify a target directory for a txt file I want to be passed?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your jar packaging. The jar file you created does not contains required dependencies. Please include required libs in your file while creating jar file. then you should be good to go.