# Generating Java Library from Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I have a few web services, and I want to be able to distribute a .jar that provides a library with which people can call those web services, but I'm unsure of how to do this. I've tried using wsimport, but it isn't able to parse one of the web services into java. I've used Axis2's wsdl2java tool, but I can't figure out how to compile the resulting java files into a single .jar library.

So far I've tried creating a project with wsdl2java's generated .java files in NetBeans, including the axiom libraries, compiling it using [these instructions](http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html), and including the resulting .jar in other projects with which I need to use the web service, but when I do, I get this error upon running the project (unless I include the axiom-impl jar):

> No meta factory found for feature 'default'; this usually means that axiom-impl.jar is not in the classpath

How can I take a WSDL and, from it, generate a single .jar allowing me to call those web services in java?

Comment: Are you asking for distributing jar with web service client or web service itself?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want people with the .jar to be able to call the web service. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Have you considered just using the "wsimport" tool in the JDK?

Comment: Huh, thought I mentioned this is the question, but apparently I forgot. wsimport has trouble parsing one of the WSDLs, but wsdl2java does it just fine.

Comment: maybe that method is missing something. other options can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059851/is-it-possible-to-package-all-the-jar-dependencies-in-one-big-jar