# Building executable from different jars

Tags: java, jar

I wrote a program where various java library's used in the program. I made a jar file of my program using netbeans. Now if I use that jar on any other location, then I will have to manually include all the jar libraries.

Is there any way so that all the dependent libraries should get build with my program's jar to build a single jar instead of so many jar files ?

I know there are programs which converts jar to exe, they also do the same thing but I want to get the last file into jar format, so that it could also run on Linux.

Thanks

Comment: How are you building your jar? It's certainly possible (It's referred to as a fat-jar, or a jar-with-dependencies), but the simplest way to create them depends on your build tool.

Comment: Seems like you are not building an **executable** (like an `.exe`), but packaging everything in a fat jar. If that is the case this question has already been asked at least once. [Is it possible to package all the jar dependencies in one big jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059851/is-it-possible-to-package-all-the-jar-dependencies-in-one-big-jar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be done. Since you are using Netbeans, this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-build-fat-jar-using) may help you.

Comment: How would you describe the necessary steps with your own words? (without linking to outside of stackoverflow)

Comment: @slartidan Sorry, I linked an article because it's bit longer to summarize all the steps here.

Comment: [Meta-Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 5):

You can use use [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)

One-JAR provides custom classloader that knows how to load classes and resources from a jars inside an archive, instead of from jars in the filesystem. It discovers dependency jar files based on the internal structure of the archive, there is no custom code required to do this. One-JAR archives can be constructed using Ant or Maven2. Your application can be run using java -jar my-app.jar

Using Maven: you need to update the `plugins` section `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
        <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>one-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And update `pluginRepositories` section in `pom.xml`

```
<pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
</pluginRepository>
```

When you will execute the `mvn package` you will get `yourappname-one-jar.jar` and you can run it `java -jar yourappname-one-jar.jar`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using maven, this maven-shade-plugin is what you are looking for: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/